# Complex Views/Taxonomy display

Tags: 7, views, entities

I am trying to build a menu page for a restaurant and I am stuck. Essentially, I need it to match the picture attached. I am using nodes with fields grouped with the Field Collection module and using views to render this data.

Any help appreciated.

[See link to image outlining my desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfStv.png)

Comment: Why are you building a menu with taxonomy?  For a restaurant menu, I think the normal approach is just to use a normal HTML page.

Comment: The point is to make it easier to manage for the end client and two, food elements are used across multiple menus.

Comment: How many items/sets are you talking about?  You could use the built-in blocks system instead, which is built to allow the layout to be easily manipulated (and can be further controlled with Panels, etc.)  You could also set up WSYIWYG editing to make it easier on the client.